# How to mock an SqlDataReader using Moq - Update

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm new to moq and setting up mocks so i could do with a little help. How do I mock up an SqlDataReader using Moq?

Update

After further testing this is what I have so far:

```
private IDataReader MockIDataReader()
{
    var moq = new Mock<IDataReader>();
    moq.Setup( x => x.Read() ).Returns( true );
    moq.Setup( x => x.Read() ).Returns( false );
    moq.SetupGet<object>( x => x["Char"] ).Returns( 'C' );

    return moq.Object;
}

private class TestData
{
    public char ValidChar { get; set; }
}

private TestData GetTestData()
{
   var testData = new TestData();

   using ( var reader = MockIDataReader() )
   {
       while ( reader.Read() )
       {
           testData = new TestData
           {
               ValidChar = reader.GetChar( "Char" ).Value
           };
       }
   }

   return testData;
}
```

The issue you is when I do reader.Read in my GetTestData() method its always empty. I need to know how to do something like

```
reader.Stub( x => x.Read() ).Repeat.Once().Return( true )
```

as per the rhino mock example: [Mocking a DataReader and getting a Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: IDisposable.Dispose(); Expected #0, Actual #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792984/mocking-a-datareader-and-getting-a-rhino-mocks-exceptions-expectationviolationexc)

Comment: I have no experience in mocking the SqlDataReader but, if you can, you should mock the interface. I've looked it up for you and maybe this article could help ya :] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792984/mocking-a-datareader-and-getting-a-rhino-mocks-exceptions-expectationviolationexc It uses Rhinomocks but the idea is the same. Suggested there, you should Mock IDataReader. When you've mocked that, you shouldn't have problems doing .Setups() on the mock ^^ If you've already tried mocking an interface, maybe you could show us where you get stuck by posting some example code :]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Moq has an ability to run some code after the method is executed. It is called "Callback". 
Modify your code this way and it will work:

```
private IDataReader MockIDataReader()
{
    var moq = new Mock<IDataReader>();

    bool readToggle = true;

    moq.Setup(x => x.Read())
         // Returns value of local variable 'readToggle' (note that 
         // you must use lambda and not just .Returns(readToggle) 
         // because it will not be lazy initialized then)
        .Returns(() => readToggle) 
        // After 'Read()' is executed - we change 'readToggle' value 
        // so it will return false on next calls of 'Read()'
        .Callback(() => readToggle = false); 

    moq.Setup(x => x["Char"])
        .Returns('C');

    return moq.Object;
}

private class TestData
{
    public char ValidChar { get; set; }
}

private TestData GetTestData()
{
    var testData = new TestData();

    using ( var reader = MockIDataReader() )
    {
       testData = new TestData
       {
           ValidChar = (Char)reader["Char"]
       };
   }

   return testData;
}
```

But what if it will be required IDataReader to contain not only single row, but several? Well, here is a sample:

```
// You should pass here a list of test items, their data
// will be returned by IDataReader
private IDataReader MockIDataReader(List<TestData> ojectsToEmulate)
{
    var moq = new Mock<IDataReader>();

    // This var stores current position in 'ojectsToEmulate' list
    int count = -1;

    moq.Setup(x => x.Read())
        // Return 'True' while list still has an item
        .Returns(() => count < ojectsToEmulate.Count - 1)
        // Go to next position
        .Callback(() => count++);

    moq.Setup(x => x["Char"])
        // Again, use lazy initialization via lambda expression
        .Returns(() => ojectsToEmulate[count].ValidChar);

    return moq.Object;
}
```

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone else, in the Returns method the brackets in () => are critical... if you don't use them you'll find yourself in an infinite loop

Answer (score 18):

I was just trying to figure this out myself. Not sure if this is new functionality in Moq, but it appears there is a simpler way than @Monsignor's answer.

Use Moq's `SetupSequence` method. Your code simply becomes:

```
private IDataReader MockIDataReader()
{
    var moq = new Mock<IDataReader>();
    moq.SetupSequence( x => x.Read() )
       .Returns( true )
       .Returns( false );
    moq.SetupGet<object>( x => x["Char"] ).Returns( 'C' );

    return moq.Object; 
}
```

Comment: Can you return more than one object using this approach?

Answer (score 8):

This does not let you mock a `SqlDataReader` but if your function is returning a `DbDataReader` (The base class of `SqlDataReader`) or a `IDataReader` the easist way to mock it is just use a `DataTable` or a `DataSet` and call its [`CreateDataReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135401(v=vs.110).aspx) function and return that.

First, in a separate project, run your query like normal to produce some test data and use the `WriteXmlSchema` to generate a .xsd file and the `WriteXml` functions to hold the test data.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Some query", con))
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("TestDataSet");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("FirstSet");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }

        ds.WriteXmlSchema(@"C:\Temp\TestDataSet.xsd");
        ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Temp\TestDataSetData.xml");
    }
}
```

In your test project add `TestDataSet.xsd` to the project and make sure it has the custom tool of `MSDataSetGenerator` (it should have it by default). This will cause a `DataTable` derived class named `TestDataSet` to be generated that has the schema of your query.

Then add `TestDataSetData.xml` as a resource to your test project. Finally in your test create the `TestDataSet` and call `ReadXml` using the text from the xml file you generated.

```
var resultSet = new TestData.TestDataSet();
using (var reader = new StringReader(Resources.TestDataSetData))
{
    resultSet.ReadXml(reader);
}

var testMock = new Mock<DbCommand>();

testMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteReader())
    .Returns(resultSet.CreateDataReader);

testMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    .ReturnsAsync(resultSet.CreateDataReader);
```

This will create a data reader that will act just like the data reader that would have been returned from the sql query and even supports things like multiple result sets returned.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing the problem is trying to set the DataReader.Read() to true for one loop and then setting it to false. Rhino Mock has the Repeat.Once() option but I could not find a similar method in Moq (I might be wrong here).

The main reason for testing this was the extension methods to convert the reader to the relevant datatype so in the end I removed the while loop and just accessed the values that had been setup in my mock. The code looks as follows:

```
private IDataReader MockIDataReader()
{
    var moq = new Mock<IDataReader>();
    moq.SetupGet<object>( x => x["Char"] ).Returns( 'C' );

    return moq.Object;
}

private class TestData
{
    public char ValidChar { get; set; }
}

private TestData GetTestData()
{
    var testData = new TestData();

    using ( var reader = MockIDataReader() )
    {
       testData = new TestData
       {
           ValidChar = reader.GetChar( "Char" ).Value
       };
   }

   return testData;
}
```

Not an ideal solution but it works. If anyone knows better leave a comment thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @mikesigs answer and another question: [SetupSequence in Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308328/setupsequence-in-moq)
I've came up with the following extension method that does the work for you:

```
    public static void SetupDataReader(this Mock<IDataReader> dataReaderMock, IList<string> columnNames, ICollection collection)
    {
        var queue = new Queue(collection);

        dataReaderMock
            .Setup(x => x.Read())
            .Returns(() => queue.Count > 0)
            .Callback(() =>
            {
                if (queue.Count > 0)
                {
                    var row = queue.Dequeue();
                    foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
                    {
                        var columnValue = row.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(row);
                        dataReaderMock
                            .Setup(x => x[columnNames.IndexOf(columnName)])
                            .Returns(columnValue);
                        dataReaderMock
                            .Setup(x => x[columnName])
                            .Returns(columnValue);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

And the usage example:

```
        var foundTargetIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var dataReaderMock = new Mock<IDataReader>();
        dataReaderMock.SetupDataReader(new[] { "TargetId" }, foundTargetIds.Select(x => new { TargetId = x }).ToList());
```