# SetupSequence in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I want a mock that returns `0` the first time, then returns `1` anytime the method is called thereafter. The problem is that if the method is called 4 times, I have to write:

```
mock.SetupSequence(x => x.GetNumber())
    .Returns(0)
    .Returns(1)
    .Returns(1)
    .Returns(1);
```

Otherwise, the method returns null.

Is there any way to write that, after the initial call, the method returns `1`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

That's not particulary fancy, but I think it would work:

```
    var firstTime = true;

    mock.Setup(x => x.GetNumber())
        .Returns(()=>
                        {
                            if(!firstTime)
                                return 1;

                            firstTime = false;
                            return 0;
                        });
```

Comment: I think this isn't thread-safe though, so in case your test involve code that invokes `GetNumber` from different threads - you might get `1` returned more than once. To achieve thread-safety, the `Interlocked` class can be used for read / write of `firstTime`.

Comment: While it's pretty safe for the given scenario, you shouldn't get too comfortable using `if` statements in test logic. _Explanation_: https://www.typemock.com/avoid-logic-inside-a-unit-test/

Answer (score 79):

The cleanest way is to create a `Queue` and pass `.Dequeue` method to `Returns`

`.Returns(new Queue<int>(new[] { 0, 1, 1, 1 }).Dequeue);`

Comment: @RomainVerdier - No, it doesn't. I think the OP asks for a solution with 4 invocations.

Comment: All - avoid my initial mistake. If you define it such that you have Returns(myQueue.Dequeue()) then you will only get the first result back - because you have actually dequeued  the  result, instead of supplying a lambda expression.

Comment: @sfuqua - that's why my answer uses a delegate instead of invocation.

Comment: @JakubKonecki yes, exactly. I'm just warning others to follow that pattern precisely and do not accidentally Dequeue() as I did.

Comment: Small problem - Moq will not raise an exception if this setup was called less than 4 times.

Comment: @ben I like to put my exception throwing Moq statements (Verify's) in an Assert block (Arrange, Act, Assert) at the end of the test anyway, where you can cleanly check if something was called an exact number of times

Comment: Simple, yet efficient. Love it

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Much more elegant.

Comment: I don't understand... this will be valid only 4 times, and afterwards not, isn't so?
this is not what the OP asked for

Comment: I only get the first entry back, even if I use a delegate instead of a invocation. I'm using Moq 4, is that a problem?

Comment: Same problem that  @Dominik has, this does not seem to work in Moq 4 ...

Answer (score 31):

Bit late to the party, but if you want to still use Moq's API, you could call the `Setup` function in the action on the final `Returns` call:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.GetNumber())
    .Returns(4)
    .Returns(() =>
    {
        // Subsequent Setup or SetupSequence calls "overwrite" their predecessors: 
        // you'll get 1 from here on out.
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetNumber()).Returns(1);
        return 1;
    });

var o = mock.Object;
Assert.Equal(4, o.GetNumber());
Assert.Equal(1, o.GetNumber());
Assert.Equal(1, o.GetNumber());
// etc...
```

I wanted to demonstrate using `SetupSequence`, but for the OP's specific case, you could simplify and have everything in a `Setup` method:

```cs
mock.Setup(m => m.GetNumber())
    .Returns(() =>
    {
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetNumber()).Returns(1);
        return 4;
    });
```

Tested everything here with *xunit@2.4.1* and *Moq@4.14.1* - passes ✔

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with "ReturnsAsync". You can't have a lamda expression inside the method as a parameter. Maybe it works for non asynchronous development, but who does that nowadays?

Comment: The question wasn't about async development 

Comment: In newer Moq official docs it is recommended to do `.Setup(x => x.FooAsync().Result).Returns(bar)` over `.Setup(x => x.FooAsync()).ReturnsAsync(bar)`.

I havent tested it with SetupSequence, but perhaps it'll help.

Answer (score 12):

Normally, I wouldn't bother submitting a new answer to such an old question, but in recent years `ReturnsAsync` has become very common, which makes potential answers more complicated.

As other have stated, you can essentially just create a queue of results and in your `Returns` call pass the `queue.Dequeue` delegate, e.g.:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(new[ ]{0,1,2,3});
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.Bar()).Returns(queue.Dequeue);
```

However, if you are setting up for an async method, we should normally call `ReturnsAsync`. `queue.Dequeue` when passed into `ReturnsAsync` will result in the first call to the method being setup working correctly, but subsequent calls to throw a `NullReferenceException`. You could as some of the other examples have done create your own extension method which returns a task, however this approach does not work with `SetupSequence`, and must use `Returns` instead of `ReturnsAsync`. Also, having to create an extension method to handle returning the results kind of defeats the purpose of using Moq in the first place. And in any case, any method which has a return type of Task where you have passed a delegate to `Returns` or `ReturnsAsync` will always fail on the second call when setting up via `SetupSequence`.

There are however two amusing alternatives to this approach that require only minimal additional code. The first option is to recognize that the mock object's `Setup` and `SetupAsync` methods follow the Fluent API design pattern. What this means, is that technically, `Setup`, `SetupAsync`, `Returns` and `ReturnsAsync` actually all return a "Builder" object. What I'm referring to as a Builder type object are fluent api style objects like `QueryBuilder`, `StringBuilder`, `ModelBuilder` and `IServiceCollection`/`IServiceProvider`. The practical upshot of this is that we can easily do this:

```
var queue = new List<int>(){0,1,2,3};
var setup = mock.SetupSequence(m => m.BarAsync());
foreach(var item in queue)
{
  setup.ReturnsAsync(item);
}
```

This approach allows us to use both `SetupSequence` and `ReturnsAsync`, which in my opinion follows the more intuitive design pattern.

The second approach is to realize that `Returns` is capable of accepting a delegate which returns a `Task`, and that `Setup` will always return the same thing. This means that if we were to create an an extension method for `Queue<T>` like this:

```
public static class EMs
{
  public static async Task<T> DequeueAsync<T>(this Queue<T> queue)
  {
    return queue.Dequeue();
  }
}
```

Then we could simply write:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(new[] {0,1,2,3});
mock.Setup(m => m.BarAsync()).Returns(queue.DequeueAsync);
```

Or would could make use of the `AsyncQueue` class from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading`, which would allow us to do this:

```
var queue = new AsyncQueue<int>(new[] {0,1,2,3});
mock.Setup(m => m.BarAsync()).Returns(queue.DequeueAsync);
```

The main problem that causes all of this, as that when the end of a setup sequence has been reached, the method is treated as not being setup. To avoid this, you are expected to also call a standard `Setup` if results should be returned after the end of the sequence has been reached.

I have put together a fairly comprehensive fiddle regarding this functionality with examples of the errors you may encounter when doing things wrong, as well as examples of several different ways you can do things correctly.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KbJlxb

Comment: Awesome answer. Ran right smack into null ref and this fixed it immediately

Answer (score 6):

You can use a temporary variable to keep track of how many times the method was called.

Example:

```
public interface ITest
{ Int32 GetNumber(); }

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Mock<ITest>();

        var f = 0;
        a.Setup(x => x.GetNumber()).Returns(() => f++ == 0 ? 0 : 1);

        Debug.Assert(a.Object.GetNumber() == 0);
        for (var i = 0; i<100; i++)
            Debug.Assert(a.Object.GetNumber() == 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just setup an extension method like:

```
public static T Denqueue<T>(this Queue<T> queue)
{
    var item = queue.Dequeue();
    queue.Enqueue(item);
    return item;
}
```

And then setup the return like:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>(new []{0, 1, 1, 1});
mock.Setup(m => m.GetNumber).Returns(queue.Denqueue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Moq uses the [builder pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder), setting up the behavior of the mocks.
You **can, but don't have to** use the [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C#).
Keeping that in mind, I solved the problem this way:

```
var sequence = myMock
            .SetupSequence(""the method I want to set up"");

foreach (var item in stuffToReturn)
{    
  sequence = sequence.Returns(item);
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This works for me because myMock is created with Strict behaviour. I need exactly 6 items to perform my test.