# How to mock multiple query strings?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, request.querystring

I want to mock(by moq) multiple QueryStrings in my unit testing class.
Below is the piece of code :-

```
Adapter.MockQueryString("qs1", "1", _productController); 
Adapter.MockQueryString("qs2", "1", _productController);
```

And below is my static function of Adapter class :-

```
   public static void MockQueryString(string querystringKey, string querystringValue, Controller controller)
   {
       var queryString1 = new NameValueCollection();
       queryString1.Add(querystringKey, querystringValue);

       // Set up a request
       var request = new Mock<System.Web.HttpRequestBase>();
       request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString1);

       // Inject into the controller
       var controllerBase = new Mock<ControllerBase>();
       var contextBase = new Mock<System.Web.HttpContextBase>();
       contextBase.Setup(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

       request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryString1);
       var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(contextBase.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), controllerBase.Object);
       controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
   }
```

> > Problem is its only mocking the last query string (qs2).And giving null for qs1.How we can mock multiple query strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Moq has [`SetupSequence`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11308328/314291), which allows you to return different results after each invocation of the Mock

```
request.SetupSequence(r => r.QueryString)
       .Returns(queryString1)
       .Returns(queryString2);
```

You may have to adjust your setup to accept a collection

**Edit**

In the general case, you may be better off using `Setup` with a stateful mechanism, e.g. accessing an iterator via a closure:

```
public static void MockQueryString(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> qstringTuples, 
                                   Controller controller)
{
    // Convert collection to IEnum<NameValueCollection>
    var queryStrings = qstringTuples
        .Select(_ => new NameValueCollection {{_.Item1, _.Item2}})
        .ToList();
    // Set up a request
    var request = new Mock<System.Web.HttpRequestBase>();
    var queryStringIterator = queryStrings.GetEnumerator();
    request.SetupGet(r => r.QueryString)
           .Returns(() =>
                        {
                            queryStringIterator.MoveNext();
                            return queryStringIterator.Current;
                        });
```

Comment: @SturartLC,can you suggest the whole process ?

Comment: I'm not 100% of your requirement, but the above approach allows you to preset N values to be returned from your Mock to your SUT. `SetupSequence` would work best in a simple Unit Test with a few calls to `QueryString`, but since you seem to have abstracted a framework for setup, you may want to do the general sense of sequentially returning each of a collection of values on subsequent calls. Note an earlier error in my setup -> QueryString is a property, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting up a property to return an object (the `NameValueCollection` with `qs1`), and then setting it up to return a different object (a different `NameValueCollection` with `qs2`).  The second `SetUp` replaces the first one, which is why you always get the `qs2` string.

Build the `NameValueCollection` outside of `MockQueryString` and pass that in, so you set up the property return value only once:

```
public static void MockQueryStrings(NameValueCollection queryStrings, Controller controller)
{
    // Set up a request
    var request = new Mock<System.Web.HttpRequestBase>();
    request.Setup(r => r.QueryString).Returns(queryStrings);

    ... etc
}
```

Then invoke `MockQueryStrings` once:

```
var queryStrings = new NameValueCollection();
queryStrings.Add("qs1", "1");
queryStrings.Add("qs2", "2");
Adapter.MockQueryStrings(queryStrings, _productController);
```