# Moq to return one set of values on first invocation and then to return second set of values for all susequent invocations

Tags: c#, .net, testing, moq

I have tried

Option 1

```
         var invocations = 0;
        _mockSqsMessageManager.Setup(x => x.GetMessages())
            .ReturnsAsync(() => invocations > 0 ? new List<SqsMessage>() : messages)
            .Callback(() =>
            {
                invocations++;
            });
```

Option 2

```
            _mockSqsMessageManager.Setup(x => x.GetMessages())
            .ReturnsAsync(messages)
            .Callback(() =>
            {
                _mockSqsMessageManager.Setup(x => x.GetMessages())
                    .ReturnsAsync(new List<SqsMessage>());
            });
```

Option 3

```
            var invocations = 0;
        _mockSqsMessageManager.Setup(x => x.GetMessages())
            .ReturnsAsync(messages)
            .Callback(() =>
            {
                invocations++;
                if (invocations > 0)
                {
                    messages = new List<SqsMessage>();
                }
            });
```

Option 4

```
        _mockSqsMessageManager.Setup(x => x.GetMessages())
            .ReturnsAsync(() =>
            {
                var invocations = _mockSqsMessageManager.Invocations.Count(x => x.MatchingSetup.Expression.Body.ToString() == "x.GetMessages()");
                return invocations > 0 ? new List<SqsMessage>() : messages;
            });
```

Option 5

```
            _mockSqsMessageManager.SetupSequence(x => x.GetMessages())
            .ReturnsAsync(messages)
            .ReturnsAsync(new List<SqsMessage>());
```

None have worked reliably. Option 5 works but if I only have the exact amount of invocations. I may have more than 100+ invocations so I can't use `SetupSequence`.

Comment: Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308328/setupsequence-in-moq with some other options.

Comment: I have answered my own question, please check. Your recommendation for the post prompted me to think about thread safety. I have a working solution now with locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was thread safety since the mock was being called from a `TransformBlock` of [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Creating a lock and ensuring unique access to the resource worked.

```
object getMessagesLocker = new();
var fetchedMessages = false;
var noMessages = Enumerable.Empty<SqsMessage>();

_mockSqsMessageManager.Setup(x => x.GetMessages())
.ReturnsAsync(() =>
{
    lock (getMessagesLocker)
    {
        if (fetchedMessages == false)
        {
            fetchedMessages = true;
            return messages;
        }

        return noMessages;
    }
});
```

BTW, I tested option 4 on single-threaded execution where mock is called only on from the main thread and that works fine.