C# Unit Test: Concurrent Requests with MemoryCache and SemaphoreSlim
I'm unit testing a service that fetches data from an API and caches it using IMemoryCache and SemaphoreSlim to handle concurrency. I want to simulate a scenario with multiple concurrent requests where:

The first request bypasses the cache, fetches data from the API, and
populates the cache.
Subsequent requests hit the cache and avoid
redundant API calls.

In my test, I'm using a real MemoryCache instance instead of mocking it. Is this a good approach, or are there better ways to achieve this scenario in my unit test? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Here is my unit test
public async Task GetSigningKeysFromJwkAsync_ConcurrentRequests_OnlyOneFetchAndOthersUseCache()
{
    // Arrange
    var httpClient = HttpClient();
    var mockHttpClientFactory = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();
    mockHttpClientFactory.Setup(factory
        => factory.CreateClient("client")).Returns(httpClient);
    var memoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());  // This is the question
    var publicKeyService = new PublicKeyService(mockHttpClientFactory.Object, memoryCache);
    var bffUrl = new Uri("https://dummy-link/jwks");


    // Act
    var tasks = new List<Task<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SecurityKey>>>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // Simulate 10 concurrent requests
    {
        tasks.Add(publicKeyService.GetSigningKeysFromJwkAsync(bffUrl));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    // Assert

    var firstResult = tasks[0].Result;
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        Assert.Equal(firstResult, task.Result);
    }
}

Here is my method which I am trying to test
public async Task<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SecurityKey>>?> GetSigningKeysFromJwkAsync(Uri url)
{
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(_cacheKey, out Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SecurityKey>>? cachedKeys))
    {
        return cachedKeys;
    }

    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(_cacheKey, out cachedKeys))
        {
            return cachedKeys;
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var jwksJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var issuerKeys = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jwksJson);

        var issuerSecurityKeySet = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SecurityKey>>();
        if (issuerKeys != null && issuerKeys.Any())
        {
            foreach (var ik in issuerKeys)
            {
                var jwks = new JsonWebKeySet(ik.Value);
                issuerSecurityKeySet.Add(ik.Key, jwks.GetSigningKeys());
            }
        }

        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
            .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        _cache.Set(_cacheKey, issuerSecurityKeySet, cacheEntryOptions);

        return issuerSecurityKeySet;
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
} 


It is just the naming: testing against mocked dependencies => Unit Test, testing against real dependencies => Integration Test

You're right, the distinction between unit and integration tests can be blurry sometimes. In this case, I want to focus on testing the concurrent behavior of my code with the IMemoryCache.
Using a real MemoryCache allows me to test the actual locking mechanism (SemaphoreSlim) and verify that:
Only one thread fetches data from the API while others wait.
Once the cache is populated, subsequent threads retrieve data from the cache and avoid redundant API calls. Any way I would like to check with this question whether it is possible to achieve the same with Mocking IMemory Cache.

What are you trying to achieve by mocking this? Also: I wonder whether HybridCache (alongside .net 9, but not tied to .net 9) might be interesting here.

Yes, l want to Mock lMemoryCache to achieve same results

But... why? Genuine question. The default memory cache is already isolated enough, IMO

In unit tests we should try to avoid using concrete classes, right? Please correct me if lm wrong and secondly, yes the current unit test is solving the purpose, just want to know if this is the right and best way..

Mock memory cache can be set up like code below.
var expectedKeys = new Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<SecurityKey>> { { "issuer1", new List<SecurityKey>() }, { "issuer2", new List<SecurityKey>() } }; 
var mockMemoryCache = new Mock<IMemoryCache>(); 
var firstTime = true; 
object? expectedValue = expectedKeys;
mockMemoryCache.Setup(x => x.TryGetValue(It.IsAny<object>(), out expectedValue))
          .Returns(() =>
          {
              if (firstTime)
              {
                  firstTime = false;
                  return false;
              }
              return true;
          });

mockMemoryCache
.Setup(x => x.CreateEntry(It.IsAny<object>()))
.Returns(Mock.Of<ICacheEntry>);

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308543/8778795
https://github.com/devlooped/moq/issues/436

Thanks Bo, I made a slight modification to the above code, and it worked, since the return type is Dictionary<string, IEnumerable>( if possible, edit your answer as I can't).                                                                                                                          var expectedKeys = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable>
{
{ "issuer1", new List() },
{ "issuer2", new List() }
};
var mockMemoryCache = new Mock();
var firstTime = true;
object? expectedValue = expectedKeys;

I agree with approach to use real implementation of IMemoryCache, instead of mocking it.
Mocking it will be cumbersome, as you would need to setup a return values for multiple calls (which could be done for example with SetupSequence from Moq nuget).
In your scenario, you would need to setup first two calls to return nothing, so code can get through to fetching data with HttpClient.
But if you want to test it in parallel, it can happen that two parallel calls would "consume" empty results from cache, and in this case, each of these calls and every subsequent call would not reach HttpClient, which would be wrong.
So, just use the real thing :) I don't see any future problems with that. Some say that if dependency is not mocked, it is part of a test and test is fragile and prone to failures.
But I consider this dependency rather stable and no need to be mocked (it does not do complex thing to be abstracted away, in fact it does exactly what we need here).
