# RhinoMocks Unexpected Dispose()

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Unexpected behaviour from RhinoMocks:

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var connection = mocks.Stub<OracleConnection>();
var command = mocks.Stub<OracleCommand>();

using (mocks.Record()) {
    connection.Expect(x => x.CreateCommand()).Return(command);
    command.Expect(x => x.ExecuteNonQuery());
    command.Expect(x => x.Dispose());
}

using (mocks.Playback()) {
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        ...
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Allthough I have expected the Dispose()-Call, it is not recognized and I am getting the following message:

```
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: IDisposable.Dispose(); Expected #0, Actual #1.
```

If I rewirte the code without the using-clause everything is fine:

```
OracleCommand cmd = null;
try {
    command = connection.CreateCommand();
    ...
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally {
    if (command != null)
        command.Dispose();
}
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Regards, 
MacX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792984/mocking-a-datareader-and-getting-a-rhino-mocks-exceptions-expectationviolationexc) suggest that the problem may stem from the fact that you are stubbing out `OracleCommand`, rather than an IDbCommand or similar.

The comments on the accepted answer suggest that if `OracleCommand` is an abstract class, you should be mocking it using `GeneratePartialMock<OracleCommand>()`.

I hope this helps you.

### edit

In response to your comment, it sounds like you need the implementation-specific methods of `OracleCommand`, but can't mock it properly.

Although `OracleCommand` is sealed, you could wrap it compositionally. It takes some legwork, but will allow you to both use `OracleCommand` in your code and mock it in your tests.

```
public interface IOracleCommand : IDbCommand
{
    void OracleMethod();
    string OracleProperty { get; set; }
}

public class OracleCommandWrapper : IOracleCommand
{
    private OracleCommand _inner;

    public OracleCommandWrapper(OracleCommand inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public IDbDataParameter CreateParameter()
    {
        return _inner.CreateParameter();
    }

    // do this for all the members, including the Oracle-specific members

    public void OracleMethod()
    {
        _inner.OracleMethod();
    }

    public string OracleProperty
    {
        get { return _inner.OracleProperty; }
        set { _inner.OracleProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use `IOracleCommand` and `OracleCommandWrapper` in your code, and in your tests you just mock or stub off of the `IOracleCommand` interface.

Again, it takes some legwork, but gets you where you want to be.

Comment: Due to the fact that OracleConnection-Class and others are sealed, I get a 'System.NotSupportedException: Can't create mocks of sealed classes.'-Message while creating the mock. So this is not an opportunity. Otherwise A testing directly to the database is not really what I want

Comment: @MacX - OracleConnection derives from DbConnection, which implements IDbConnection.  This is the interface you want to mock and inject, instead of creating an instance/mock/stub/etc. of OracleConnection.

Comment: This would be an opportunity, in general. But in fact, I need some special features provided by Oracle's implementation for example the arraybinding for large inserts - [Oracle's ArrayBinding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/BulkOperationsUsingOracleDataProviderForNETODPNET.aspx)

Comment: thats quite an overhead for my needs i think. while this problem doen't make me more do than rewrite the using-clauses, I would prefer the rewrite than wrapping Oracle, but many thanks anyway